# How to resolve the following AspectJ aspect ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

The book Spring In Action has the following example. It uses AspectJ's aspect to illustrate constructor pointcuts.

Example:

```
package com.ct.springidol;
public aspect JudgeAspect {
    public JudgeAspect() {

    }

    private CriticismEngine criticismEngine;

    //Constructor injection is supposed to happen
    public void setCriticismEngine(CriticismEngine criticismEngine) {
        this.criticismEngine = criticismEngine;
    }

    pointcut performance(): execution( * perform(..));

    after() returning(): performance() {
        System.out.println(criticismEngine.getCriticism());
    }
}

package com.ct.springidol;
public class CriticismEngineImpl implements CriticismEngine {
    //CriticismEngine - an interface -  has only getCriticism() method.

    public CriticismEngineImpl() {

    }

    private String[] criticismsPool;
    //injected using xml file
    public void setCriticismsPool(String[] criticismsPool) {
        this.criticismsPool = criticismsPool;
    }

    public String getCriticism() {
        int i = (int) (Math.random() * criticismsPool.length);
        return criticismsPool[i];
    }
}
```

The corresponding XML:

```
<bean id="criticismEngine"
      class="com.ct.springidol.CriticismEngineImpl">
    <property name="criticismsPool">
        <list>
            <value>I'm not being rude, but that was appalling.</value>
            <value>You may be the least talented person in this show.</value>
            <value>Do everyone a favor and keep your day job.</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean class="com.ct.springidol.JudgeAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">
    <property name="criticismEngine" ref="criticismEngine"/>
</bean>
```

But When I run the program i.e. the `perform()` method is run I am getting the following exception. How to resolve this? FYI, I have both `aspectjrt` and `aspectjweaver` in my maven dependency.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main"
    org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException:
    Cannot find class [com.ct.springidol.JudgeAspect] for bean with name
    'com.ct.springidol.JudgeAspect#0' defined in class path resource
    [spring-idol.xml]; nested exception is
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ct.springidol.JudgeAspect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using IntelliJ. I had to configure the IDE in order to compile the aspect i.e. `JudgeAspect`. For this program to work properly, it needs compiled aspect. So, one will have to enable the `AspectJ compiler` i.e. `ajc compiler` instead of Java compiler in the compiler settings of the IDE. 
For complete details

```
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-the-aspectj-%28ajc%29-compiler.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The package declaration in your code snippet for `JudgeAspect` seems to be missing. You need it for your pointcut to match. Have you just forgotten to paste it here? It looks as though Spring cannot find its own bean. This looks like a classpath configuration problem, not really an AspectJ or Spring AOP one. I am not a Spring user, but this is what it looks like to me.

Is this your very first Spring program? Have you ever managed to get a minimal Spring project running?

Comment: Thanks for responding to my qeustion. And sorry for very delayed response. The problem is not with classpath but the IDE had to be configured. Thank you anyway.